# substr function not returning desired substring

Tags: php, substring

Suppose I have following string :

```
$str = "PHP code may be embedded into HTML or HTML5 markup, or it can be used in combination with various web template systems, web content management systems and web frameworks.";
```

Here, I'm printing the substring starting from the word 'combination', and ending upto 'content'

```
echo substr($str, strpos($str, 'combination'), strpos($str, 'content'));
```

It is printing from 'combination' and to the end, instead of upto 'content'.
Is there anything wrong in the third parameter ?

Comment: The 3rd parameter is length. https://www.w3schools.com/pHP/func_string_substr.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third argument for substr should be a string length but not the end position

```
$i = strpos($str, 'combination');
echo substr($str, $i, strpos($str, 'content') - $i);
```